# Cabal errors with cyclic dependencies, even though one `build-depends` is listed in the executable section

Tags: haskell, cabal

Why do these .cabal files create a cyclic dependency error:

```
cabal-version:      2.4
name:               red
version:            0.1.0.0

library
    build-depends: base, blue

executable red
    main-is:          Main.hs
    build-depends:    base ^>=4.15.1.0
    hs-source-dirs:   app
    default-language: Haskell2010
```

and

```
cabal-version:      2.4
name:               blue
version:            0.1.0.0

library
    build-depends: base

executable blue
    main-is:          Main.hs
    build-depends:    base ^>=4.15.1.0, red, blue
    hs-source-dirs:   app
    default-language: Haskell2010
```

As far as I understand:

- blue library depends only on base
- red library depends on base and blue
- blue executable depends on both the red library and blue library
- red executable depends on red the library, and transitively on blue library

There seems to be no circulation here, and, I suspect, when breaking up these packages, the error will go away.

Comment: I don't know the correct answer for sure, but my suspicion is that the nodes in the dependency tree/graph are packages, not components. So a corrected bullet list goes "package blue depends on base (because of the library) and red and blue (because of the executable); package red depends on base and blue (because of the library) and that's it". So now there's a cycle: blue depends on red, red depends on blue.

Comment: The relevant Cabal issue is https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/4087.